# Grails domain class String property case insensitive search

Tags: grails, groovy

I am trying to find records in my database using my service and this works:

```
def resultList = IndividualRecord.findAllWhere(citizenship: 'us')
```

but when I change citizenship to upper case, like this:

```
def resultList = IndividualRecord.findAllWhere(citizenship: 'US')
```

it no longer works. So I tried this:

```
def resultList = IndividualRecord.findAllWhere(citizenship.caseIgnoreEquals('us'))
```

but that doesn't work. Any suggestions? citizenship is a `String` property of class `IndividualRecord`.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

This will match the `citizenship` field against `'US'` case insensitively

```
def resultList = IndividualRecord.findAllByCitizenshipIlike('US')
```

Comment: Does that mean 'citizenship is like'?

Comment: Also, what if I wanted to add the criteria that IndividualRecord's 'uniqueid' is '23'. So, I want a US citizen whose uniqueid is 23. Can both of these be in the same query?

Comment: @AnonymousHuman yes, dynamic finders allow you to combine mulitple predicates

Comment: So would that be like def resultList = IndividualRecord.findAllByCitizenshipIlike('US', uniqueId: 23)?

Comment: `def resultList = IndividualRecord.findAllByCitizenshipIlikeAndUniqueId('US', 23)`

Comment: Ah...that's what I was afraid of that the function name gets longer and longer because depending on which check boxes my user checks. I may have up to seven different criteria to find by. Do you suggest any method more efficient? Thanks for your help.

Comment: Use a criteria query instead